# Adding an hyperlink in MSWord by using python-docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I am trying to add an hyperlink in a MS Word document using `docx` module for Python.

I searched everywhere (official doc, StackOverflow, Google) but found nothing.

I would like to do something like:

```
from docx import Document

document = Document()   

p = document.add_paragraph('A plain paragraph having some ')
p.add_hyperlink('Link to my site', target="http://supersitedelamortquitue.fr")
```

Anyone got an idea on how to do that?

Comment: Yes it is Possible. 
https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/384
See the Last Answer.

Comment: Thanks. how come I forgot to check github, stupide me!!

Comment: FYI... it is "now" (already few years ago), tracked in this issue: https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/74

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes we can do it. [Reference for the initial version](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/384#issuecomment-294853130)

```
import docx

def add_hyperlink(paragraph, text, url):
    # This gets access to the document.xml.rels file and gets a new relation id value
    part = paragraph.part
    r_id = part.relate_to(url, docx.opc.constants.RELATIONSHIP_TYPE.HYPERLINK, is_external=True)

    # Create the w:hyperlink tag and add needed values
    hyperlink = docx.oxml.shared.OxmlElement('w:hyperlink')
    hyperlink.set(docx.oxml.shared.qn('r:id'), r_id, )

    # Create a new run object (a wrapper over a 'w:r' element)
    new_run = docx.text.run.Run(
        docx.oxml.shared.OxmlElement('w:r'), paragraph)
    new_run.text = text

    # Set the run's style to the builtin hyperlink style, defining it if necessary
    new_run.style = get_or_create_hyperlink_style(part.document)
    # Alternatively, set the run's formatting explicitly
    # new_run.font.color.rgb = docx.shared.RGBColor(0, 0, 255)
    # new_run.font.underline = True

    # Join all the xml elements together
    hyperlink.append(new_run._element)
    paragraph._p.append(hyperlink)
    return hyperlink

document = docx.Document()
p = document.add_paragraph('A plain paragraph having some ')
add_hyperlink(p, 'Link to my site', "http://supersitedelamortquitue.fr")
document.save('demo_hyperlink.docx')

#This is only needed if you're using the builtin style above
def get_or_create_hyperlink_style(d):
    """If this document had no hyperlinks so far, the builtin
       Hyperlink style will likely be missing and we need to add it.
       There's no predefined value, different Word versions
       define it differently.
       This version is how Word 2019 defines it in the
       default theme, excluding a theme reference.
    """
    if "Hyperlink" not in d.styles:
        if "Default Character Font" not in d.styles:
            ds = d.styles.add_style("Default Character Font",
                                    docx.enum.style.WD_STYLE_TYPE.CHARACTER,
                                    True)
            ds.element.set(docx.oxml.shared.qn('w:default'), "1")
            ds.priority = 1
            ds.hidden = True
            ds.unhide_when_used = True
            del ds
        hs = d.styles.add_style("Hyperlink",
                                docx.enum.style.WD_STYLE_TYPE.CHARACTER,
                                True)
        hs.base_style = d.styles["Default Character Font"]
        hs.unhide_when_used = True
        hs.font.color.rgb = docx.shared.RGBColor(0x05, 0x63, 0xC1)
        hs.font.underline = True
        del hs

    return "Hyperlink"
```

Comment: I improved the answer to add a style similar to hyperlink (and not black non underline style)

Comment: This code didn't work for me, but [this](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/74#issuecomment-261169410) did along with [the underline fix](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/74#issuecomment-365726303) a couple comments below that.

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisT. rolled back. According to http://officeopenxml.com/WPhyperlink.php, `<w:hyperlink>` needs to be outside `<w:r>`, not inside. Manually adding explicit formatting also look wrong: in the docs I say, there's rather a reference to the predefined "hyperlink" style.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev ... sure, no problem. Have you checked it works well?

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisT. now that I've completed my program, I can say yes.