# HTML to Word docx

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-docx

I have some HTML formatted text I've got with `BeautifulSoup`. I'd like to convert all *italic* (tag i), **bold** (b) and links (a href) to Word format via `docx` run command.

I can make a paragraph:

```
p = document.add_paragraph('text')
```

I can ADD next sequence as bold/italic:

```
p.add_run('bold').bold = True
p.add_run('italic.').italic = True
```

Intuitively, I could find all particular tags (ie. `soup.find_all('i')`) and then watch indices and then concatenate partial strings...

...but maybe there's a better, more elegant way?

I don't want libraries or solutions that just convert a html page to word and save them. I want a little more control.

I got nowhere with a dictionary. Here is the code and visual wrong (from code) and right (desired) result:

```
from docx import Document
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<a href="http://someurl.you">hi, I am link</a> this is some nice regular text. <i> oooh, but I am italic</i> ' \
        ' or I can be <b>bold</b> '\
        ' or even <i><b>bold and italic</b></i>'

def get_tags(text):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")
    tags = {}
    tags["i"] = soup.find_all("i")
    tags["b"] = soup.find_all("b")

    return tags


def make_test_word():
    document = Document()

    document.add_heading('Demo HTML', 0)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

    p = document.add_paragraph(html)

    # p.add_run('bold').bold = True
    # p.add_run(' and some ')
    # p.add_run('italic.').italic = True

    file_name="demo_html.docx"
    document.save(file_name)
    os.startfile(file_name)


make_test_word()
```

[image]

Comment: How about a sample of your code and an expected output for reference?

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a bit of code to convert the text from a tkinter Text widget over to a word document, including any bold tags that the user can add.  This isn't a complete solution for you, but it may help you to start toward a working solution.  I think you're going to have to do some regex work to get the hyperlinks transferred to the word document.  Stacked formatting tags may also get tricky.  I hope this helps:

```
from docx import Document

html = 'HTML string <b>here</b>.'

html = html.split('<')
html = [html[0]] + ['<'+l for l in html[1:]]
doc = Document()
p = doc.add_paragraph()
for run in html:
    if run.startswith('<b>'):
        run = run.lstrip('<b>')
        runner = p.add_run(run)
        runner.bold = True
    elif run.startswith('</b>'):
        run = run.lstrip('</b>')
        runner = p.add_run(run)
    else:
        p.add_run(run)
doc.save('test.docx')
```

I came back to it and made it possible to parse out multiple formatting tags.  This will keep a tally of what formatting tags are in play in a list.  At each tag, a new run is created, and formatting for the run is set by the current tags in play.

```
from docx import Document
import re
import docx
from docx.shared import Pt
from docx.enum.dml import MSO_THEME_COLOR_INDEX

def add_hyperlink(paragraph, text, url):
    # This gets access to the document.xml.rels file and gets a new relation id value
    part = paragraph.part
    r_id = part.relate_to(url, docx.opc.constants.RELATIONSHIP_TYPE.HYPERLINK, is_external=True)

    # Create the w:hyperlink tag and add needed values
    hyperlink = docx.oxml.shared.OxmlElement('w:hyperlink')
    hyperlink.set(docx.oxml.shared.qn('r:id'), r_id, )

    # Create a w:r element and a new w:rPr element
    new_run = docx.oxml.shared.OxmlElement('w:r')
    rPr = docx.oxml.shared.OxmlElement('w:rPr')

    # Join all the xml elements together add add the required text to the w:r element
    new_run.append(rPr)
    new_run.text = text
    hyperlink.append(new_run)

    # Create a new Run object and add the hyperlink into it
    r = paragraph.add_run ()
    r._r.append (hyperlink)

    # A workaround for the lack of a hyperlink style (doesn't go purple after using the link)
    # Delete this if using a template that has the hyperlink style in it
    r.font.color.theme_color = MSO_THEME_COLOR_INDEX.HYPERLINK
    r.font.underline = True

    return hyperlink

html = '<H1>I want to</H1> <u>convert HTML <a href="http://www.google.com">to docx</a> in <b>bold and <i>bold italic</i></b>.</u>'

html = html.split('<')
html = [html[0]] + ['<'+l for l in html[1:]]
tags = []
doc = Document()
p = doc.add_paragraph()
for run in html:
    tag_change = re.match('(?:<)(.*?)(?:>)', run)
    if tag_change != None:
        tag_strip = tag_change.group(0)
        tag_change = tag_change.group(1)
        if tag_change.startswith('/'):
            if tag_change.startswith('/a'):
                tag_change = next(tag for tag in tags if tag.startswith('a '))
            tag_change = tag_change.strip('/')
            tags.remove(tag_change)
        else:
            tags.append(tag_change)
    else:
        tag_strip = ''
    hyperlink = [tag for tag in tags if tag.startswith('a ')]
    if run.startswith('<'):
        run = run.replace(tag_strip, '')
        if hyperlink:
            hyperlink = hyperlink[0]
            hyperlink = re.match('.*?(?:href=")(.*?)(?:").*?', hyperlink).group(1)
            add_hyperlink(p, run, hyperlink)
        else:
            runner = p.add_run(run)
            if 'b' in tags:
                runner.bold = True
            if 'u' in tags:
                runner.underline = True
            if 'i' in tags:
                runner.italic = True
            if 'H1' in tags:
                runner.font.size = Pt(24)
    else:
        p.add_run(run)
doc.save('test.docx')
```

Hyperlink function thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47666642/adding-an-hyperlink-in-msword-by-using-python-docx).  My concern here is that you will need to manually code for every HTML tag that you want to carry over to the docx.  I imagine that could be a large number. I've given some examples of tags you may want to account for.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can just save your html code as a string and do:

```
from htmldocx import HtmlToDocx

new_parser = HtmlToDocx()
new_parser.parse_html_file("html_filename", "docx_filename")
#Files extensions not needed, but tolerated
```