# python-docx Hyperlink The hyperlink is created but not clickable

Tags: python, django, python-docx

I was taking tuples from the database and creating a document with those values. Among them, I needed a hyperlink, so I wrote a function for it. However, the document was created, but it didn't work when I clicked on it, so when the document is completed and I do additional line break processing, It's working fine. Please tell me about this problem!

```
def add_hyperlink(paragraph,text, url):
    # Create a new hyperlink element
    hyperlink = OxmlElement('w:hyperlink')
    hyperlink.set(qn('w:anchor'), url)  # 하이퍼링크 URL 설정

    # Create ‘w:t’, a sub-element of hyperlink
    t = OxmlElement('w:t')
    t.text = text
    hyperlink.append(t)

    # Show hyperlink text in blue
    run = paragraph.add_run()
    run._r.append(hyperlink)
    run.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0, 0, 255)
```

In the text, it is used like this:

```
            p1 = doc.add_paragraph(f"file : ", style='Normal')
            add_hyperlink(p1,base_url + path, base_url + path)
            run = p1.runs[0]
            run.add_break(WD_BREAK.LINE)  # 줄바꿈 추가
```

Answer (score 0):

The `w:anchor` attribute is used only for the URL *fragment*, like the `"#summary"` part of `https://blog.com/somepost#summary`.

The actual URL goes in a `Relationship` element in the document.xml.rels file (part).

You're going to need a different function that does that bit.

Something like this might do the trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47666747/1902513