I used the docx Python library to generate a word document, but for some reason hyperlinks aren't showing? Works in Pages, but not Word
I have some text that should link to a webpage when you click on it. When I open the .docx file in Apple Pages, it works perfectly fine but when I open it in Microsoft Word, it's just regular text and doesn't link to anything. Anyone know what the issue could be?
It also says "Word found unreadable content in the document" upon opening.
def add_hyperlink_to_paragraph(paragraph, url, text):
    part = paragraph.part
    r_id = part.relate_to(url, qn('r:hyperlink'), is_external=True)
    hyperlink = OxmlElement('w:hyperlink')
    hyperlink.set(qn('r:id'), r_id)
    
    new_run = OxmlElement('w:r')
    rPr = OxmlElement('w:rPr')
    
    rStyle = OxmlElement('w:rStyle')
    rStyle.set(qn('w:val'), 'Hyperlink')
    rPr.append(rStyle)
    new_run.append(rPr)
    
    text_element = OxmlElement('w:t')
    text_element.text = text
    new_run.append(text_element)
    hyperlink.append(new_run)
    paragraph._element.append(hyperlink)
    return hyperlink

Function called:
add_hyperlink_to_paragraph(link_paragraph, f"https://www...com/{id}", id)


What exactly is your code? Does this Stackoverflow Question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47666642/adding-an-hyperlink-in-msword-by-using-python-docx

So the answer on this question stackoverflow_docx works for me. Here the mostly copied code. So maybe you can share your code and I can check why this is not working, or you try this code and say if the problem remains.
import docx

def add_hyperlink(paragraph, url, text):
    """
    A function that places a hyperlink within a paragraph object.

    :param paragraph: The paragraph we are adding the hyperlink to.
    :param url: A string containing the required url
    :param text: The text displayed for the url
    :return: The hyperlink object
    """

    # This gets access to the document.xml.rels file and gets a new relation id value
    part = paragraph.part
    r_id = part.relate_to(url, docx.opc.constants.RELATIONSHIP_TYPE.HYPERLINK, is_external=True)

    # Create the w:hyperlink tag and add needed values
    hyperlink = docx.oxml.shared.OxmlElement('w:hyperlink')
    hyperlink.set(docx.oxml.shared.qn('r:id'), r_id, )

    # Create a w:r element
    new_run = docx.oxml.shared.OxmlElement('w:r')

    # Create a new w:rPr element
    rPr = docx.oxml.shared.OxmlElement('w:rPr')

    # Join all the xml elements together add add the required text to the w:r element
    new_run.append(rPr)
    new_run.text = text
    hyperlink.append(new_run)

    paragraph._p.append(hyperlink)

    return hyperlink


doc = docx.Document()
p = doc.add_paragraph('Test link: ')
add_hyperlink(p, 'https://www.google.com', 'google')


doc.save('test.docx')


I added my code to my post. Are you able to identify what the issue is?

Ok with this code I get the same error as you. I am not sure yet where the error comes from. Maybe just use the other function to add the hyperlinks?
Or if you want to know it better what is wrong, I think you can do something like zip the word file and open it as xml, to check..

Or if you want to look closer at what went wrong, you can do something like: Unzip the .docx file, go into the word/ folder and open document.xml .. There you can check how your hyperlink is added..
